# Comparison operator is not working on 0 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I've been trying to answer this question which I stumbled upon Codewars.

> You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3 but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

and here is my initial answer.

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2];

function findOutlier(integers) {
  let evens = integers.filter(item => {
    if (item % 2 === 0 || item === 0) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  let odds = integers.filter(item => {
    if (item % 2 !== 0) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  if (evens.length > 1) {
    return odds[0];
  } else {
    return evens[0];
  }
}
console.log(findOutlier(array));
```

But apparently **item === 0** is not working in the code above, and it returns **[2]** as the value of **evens** (missing out 0).
Then I changed the code like below and it works!

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2];

function findOutlier(integers) {
  let evens = integers.filter(item => {
    if (item = 0 || item % 2 === 0) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  let odds = integers.filter(item => {
    if (item % 2 !== 0) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  if (evens.length > 1) {
    return odds[0];
  } else {
    return evens[0];
  }
}
console.log(findOutlier(array));
```

I'm still pretty confused about why the comparison operator didn't work in the first code.
Much appreciated it if you could help me understand..!

Comment: Filter should return a boolean not an integer. The integer 0 is considered false, which causes your buggy behavior. Furthermore, 0 mod 2 === 0 so the second check is redundant. `item = 0` is an assignment, not a comparison. Also, you can solve this task by iterating through the array exactly once in O(1) memory (in addition to input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is here**

```
let evens = integers.filter(item => {
    if (item = 0 || item % 2 === 0) {
      return item; // You are return value instead of boolean
    }
});
```

**It should be**

```
let evens = integers.filter(item => {
    return item == 0 || item % 2 == 0; // It should be returned boolean
});
```

Simply because according to [MDN's filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) say that:

> callback function is a predicate, to test each element of the array.
> *Return a value that coerces to `true` to keep the element, or to `false`
> otherwise`.*

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2];

function findOutlier(integers){
    let evens = integers.filter(item => {
        return item == 0 || item % 2 == 0;
    });
    let odds = integers.filter(item => {
        return item % 2 !== 0;
    });
    
    if(evens.length > 1) {
        return odds[0];
    } else {
        return evens[0];
    }
}
console.log(findOutlier(array));
```

## Optimize performance

```js
function findOutlier(integers){
   const result = integers.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if(curr % 2 === 0)
        acc["evens"].push(curr);
      else
        acc["odds"].push(curr);
      return acc;
    }, { evens: [],  odds: []});
    
   return result["evens"].length > 1 ? result["odds"][0] : result["evens"][0];
}
console.log(findOutlier([0, 1, 2]));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply..! Than you so much it really helped me out, especially there you explained i was returning the value not boolean. Again thank you so much

Comment: Yes. I'm glad to help you ^^!

Answer (score 1):

In the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method you need to return `true` or `false` and you are returning the `value`. And in the first case `0` will get returned as per your code and `0` is considered as a `falsy` value. so It won't show in the final result.

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2];

function findOutlier(integers) {
  let evens = integers.filter((item) => {
    if (item % 2 === 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  console.log(evens);

  let odds = integers.filter((item) => {
    if (item % 2 !== 0) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });

  console.log(odds);

  if (evens.length > 1) {
    return odds[0];
  } else {
    return evens[0];
  }
}
console.log(findOutlier(array));
```

**You can make this code more `readable` as shown in below snippet**

```js
let array = [0, 1, 2];

function findOutlier(integers) {
  let evens = integers.filter(item => item % 2 === 0);
  let odds  = integers.filter(item => item % 2 !== 0);

  if (evens.length > 1) return odds[0];
  else return evens[0];
}

console.log(findOutlier(array));
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay, and thank you so much for the help!! I didn't know i was supposed to return boolean in the filter method..! I'll keep that in mind and wow your code indeed looks way more readable. Thank you again

Comment: Glad, I could help

Answer (score 1):

The [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method receives a predicate that must return boolean value, `true` or `false`, not `item`. That's first mistake. The second one is using assignment `=` inside `if` condition. Single equal sign does not mean comparison.

To fix this, you can replace `return item` with `return true` within your first code sample. However, I would recommend you to use a simple loop.

```
function findOutlier(integers) {
  for (let item of integers) {
    if (item % 2 != 0) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return integers[0];
}
```